# Is there a name or symbol for the set of all subsets of all elements of some set of sets?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Given a set of sets $A$, we construct $A'=\{a\subseteq\bigcup A\mid a'\in A,a\subseteq a'\}$.

For $A=\{X\}$ we get $A'=2^{X}$, for $A=\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\}$ we get $A'=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\}$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one symbol that I know denotes this operation. A sort-of-two-symbol term denoting it is:
$$
\bigcup_{a\in A} \mathcal{P}(a).
$$
If you need to use this operation a lot, introduce a definition for a symbol having that value.